# Microservice redundancy issue in our architecture

Tags: microservices

We have 12 microservices deployed in our application server. Problem is, since we have a microservice for each specific function, a lot of libraries are being repeated in each microservice instead of if they are shared in larger monolithic services or app. This causes each .ear file to be large per microservice. with this, out of memory errors start to happen more often.

Is there any way to get around this? or better ways to do this?

Comment: Deploy libraries to gac?

Comment: whats gac? we are using websphere application server by the way

Comment: So your question can be boiled down to "how can I make my code smaller?"

Comment: @tom redfern:  i think its more of is there a way to share libraries between microservices?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are in the wrong direction by using a big application server do deploy each service, if I got your point correct.

In microservice approach, it is better to keep services small in size and use embedded servers, like embedded tomcat or jetty.